# How does HTML5 Boilerplate jQuery library fallback work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, boilerplate

This is a beginner question to html5 boilerplate, and javascript in general, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere, so here it goes...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

How does the second script line **checks** whether the google's CDN has been loaded or not? There's no if statement or anything to suggest that. I'm sorry if this sounds stupid. Any help?

Comment: Can the same check be executed for css imports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` is the if statement in this case. If `window.jQuery` returns `TRUE`, then anything after the `or` statement  (||) won't get loaded. If it's `FALSE`, then it'll continue on to load jquery.

Edit: Just to clarify a bit. If you do `if (var1 && var2)` in javascript, it'll evaluate BOTH variables to check if they're both true. If you make it `if (var1 || var2)`, then if the first variable evaluates to TRUE, there's no need to evaluate the rest of the expression, since it'll automatically be true either way.

In this case, that's exactly what your code is doing. If `window.jQuery` is FALSE (meaning jQuery wasn't loaded), then continue on and evaluate the next expression--which in this case loads the jquery from a local file. It's just not wrapped in an IF statement since it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery file from google CDN or anywhere is loaded, it would have been added a property `jQuery` to `window` object. Second line of your script checks if `window.jQuery` is defined or not, if not it executes the other part of `||` statement which adds a script tag having local jQuery file location src attribute to load it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Moazzam. I did more searching into JS conditional statement and it took me quite a while before I found out that that is another shorthand for an if statement which I have not seen before.