# Checking if the external JS file is loaded or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just need to check some external JS file is loaded or not on page ready.

IS it possible? Am thinking as below.

```
//get the number of `<script>` elements that have the correct `src` attribute
var len = $('script').filter(function () {
    return ($(this).attr('src') == '<external JS>');
}).length;

//if there are no scripts that match, the load it
if (len === 0) {
    $.getScript('<external JS>');
}
```

In above code do i need to give entire path to external JS to be loaded instead of `'<external JS>'`?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it's a XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Normally you shouldn't need such a check at all. I mean, just load the bloody scripts in correct order in the first place!

Comment: Just test for the existence of some variable, object or function created by that code. [This is how HTML5Boilerplate loads jQuery itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173272/how-does-html5-boilerplate-jquery-library-fallback-work) -- load it from Google's CDN, then test if `jquery` exists, and if not, load it from a local file instead.

Comment: Why do you need to check if the file is loaded?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Wrong -- if you are loading a script from a different domain, like a CDN, then it's always worth checking if that script has loaded successfully.

Comment: @Blazemonger I disagree. If the script is not loaded because the host is unreachable, what actually you can do? You want to load it from a different host? Ok, but not with JS but with server side tools like load balancers/failovers.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo [That's exactly what you do, yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173272/how-does-html5-boilerplate-jquery-library-fallback-work) It's easy and reliable to use JS for this; HTML5Boilerplate has been doing it this way for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following JS code to check whether JQuery Script is loaded fully in my html file.

function has 3 parameters, Script URL, Success callback function, Error callback function

```js
//Parameters - script URL, Callback on Complete, Error Callback
function loadScript(sScriptSrc, oCallback, oErrorback) {
  var oScript = document.createElement('script');
  oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  oScript.src = sScriptSrc;
  // most browsers
  if (oCallback) {
    oScript.addEventListener("load", oCallback);
  }
  if (oErrorback) {
    oScript.addEventListener("error", oErrorback);
  }
  // IE
  oScript.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
      if (oCallback) {
        oCallback();
      }
    }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(oScript);
}

//USAGE
var jQscr = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js';

function successJQLoad() {
  //Successful Loading Callback, Move ahead Code
}

function errorJQLoad() {
  //Error Callback
}

//Call function with appropriate parameters
loadScript(jQscr, successJQLoad, errorJQLoad);
```